# Redirect after login with php & ajax form

Tags: php, ajax, redirect, authentication

After the authentication succeeds I want to redirect to the homepage. I tried header() but it doesn't work. 
I know I can't use include or require before header, but what are the alternatives?

I can this php file on form submit. sec_session_start() and login() are functions from indepen_functions.php.

```
<?php
include_once 'indepen_functions.php';

sec_session_start(); // Our custom secure way of starting a PHP session.

if (isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])) {
  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $password = $_POST['password']; // The hashed password.

  if (login($username, $password) == true) {
    // Login success
    header('Location: ../index.php');
    exit();
  } else {
    // Login failed
    echo '{ "message": "Voer het wachtwoord en gebruikersnaam opnieuw in" }';
  }
} else {
   // The correct POST variables were not sent to this page. 
   echo 'Invalid Request';
}
```

the head of my login form:
      `<form id="loginForm" class="login-form" action="./includes/process_login.php" method="post">`

my login.js:

```
$('.login-form').validate({
 //other code..
 submitHandler: function (form) {           
      form.ajaxSubmit();           
      return false;        
 }
```

});

Comment: What is actually happening? Is this called via AJAX?

Comment: what error are u getting if any?

Comment: Did really the authentification work????...Try to test id the authentification works successfully by adding echo 'Something'; Before header('Location: ../index.php');...

Comment: Yes the authentication works. I'm am debugging the code on my localhost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some browsers require some more data to be sent after the header for it to actually work. Try sending some text after the header:

```
header('Location: /index.php');
echo 'This page has moved to <a href="../index.php">here</a>';
exit(0);
```

Update:
You need to set the option when you create the ajax form:

```
$(".login-form").validate({
  success: function(label) { alert('Success'); },
  submitHandler: function() { alert('Submit'); }
});
```

See [here](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/) for more.

Comment: Tried it, but doesn't work. I've added more information to my question, maybe that helps

Comment: try changing the class name from register-form to login-form `$('.login-form').validate({`

Comment: You're wright Greg. But I just copied the wrong code. My mistake. Is there a way to replace form.ajaxSubmit() so I can catch the return value of process_login.php?

Comment: Thanks, So you're saying that I have to put 
 `window.location = '/index.php'; ` in the success option? I tried it but that option is for validating the form while filling it in. So it is redirecting directly without submitting.
any other ideas?

Comment: Solved it! Feel free to post this in your answer.
in my login.php (same as the loginform)
`<script>
    function callback(data) {
        // 'data' is the json object returned from the server
       if(data.message = "loginOK") window.location.href='/index.php';
        alert( data.message);
    }
     jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            var options = {
                dataType:  'json',
                success:   callback
      };
</script> My proces_login.php : if (login($username, $password) == true) {echo '{ "message": "loginOK"}';`

Answer (score 1):

Just try using `header('Location: /index.php');` - the browser doesn't use the relative path

Comment: Think I may have misunderstood the question, though. Are you actually redirecting after a successful login from the ajax form? You'd need to do that on the JS side. Like, `window.location = '/index.php';`

Try returning something to say the login was successful, having set a session var on the PHP side, and then redirecting.

Comment: the relative path fix is valid. if he is actually logging in through ajax he should close the session and handle the redirect via javascript, return a json object result for a valid login status (true) or false if the if it wasn't successful

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I tried your suggention without success. Now I will try it in javascript. just a second

Comment: I have no idea how to catch the php return value in my structure:
form header: 
 `<form id="loginForm" class="login-form" action="**./includes/process_login.php**" method="post"> `
my login.js: 
`submitHandler: function (form) {
          form.ajaxSubmit();
          return false;
       }`

Answer (score 0):

Try using javascript code -

```
window.location = 'your page path';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `ob_start();` at the begin of your php file then use the `header('Location: your_url.php');` function.